# Can one program have multiple processes?

Tags: process, operating-system

after reading and searching about OS and process and threads, I checked on wiki and it said,

> A computer program is a passive
>   collection of instructions, a process
>   is the actual execution of those
>   instructions. Several processes may be
>   associated with the same program; for
>   example, opening up several instances
>   of the same program often means more
>   than one process is being executed.

Now is it possible for a program to have more than one process and I am not including the possibility of running more than one instance of the same program. I mean one instance of one program is running, is it possible for a program to have more than one process?
If yes, how? If no, why not?

I am a newbie in this, but damn curious :) 
Thanks for all your help..

Comment: It's actualy quite simple to create multiple procceses from one instance of a program. See `fork()` function in C language.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, fairly obviously - you can run two or more copies of most programs - I routinely have about 5 copies of vim running, and each of those is a separate process. As to how, the OS loads the executable file, creates a process and then tells that process to start executing the file contents.

Comment: I mentioned above, that I am NOT including the case where you want to run more than one instance of the program. I mean Can one instance of the program run in multiple process?

Comment: I am a bit confused here. Sorry if i am being wrong here, but I need to understand what I am reading clearly, hence the questions... Ok let me rephrase it, If im running lets say firefox, and it has two tabs, does firefox run in one process and two tabs are created as a separate process and they are communicating with the firefox process, and internally each process has its own threads, or one whole process of firefox is running and both tabs are running in separate threads...?

Comment: One process, maybe (or maybe not) two threads. If you are on windows, you can use a tool like process explorer (or ps on linux) to see exactly what is going on.

Comment: Ok I did ps and I got one main process for firefox, and two other processes are spawned by firefox for two plugins namely flash and gtalk.One more thing, you said OS can spawn more processes from one process, on what basis it decides it should spawn another process ? Does it have to be explicitly be told by the programmer who is writing the code or the OS can do it by itself if it sees fit...?

Comment: OK, what you have there is a single firefox process, and several plugin processes. In order to understand this, you would need a fairly good understanding of the FF on Linux architecture.

Comment: Yes, it is up to the programmer to decide a process should spawn child processes (or threads).

Comment: Ok Thanks a Lot. One last thing, can OS spawn a child or a thread on its own for a program, if it feels it will make it more optimised or any other reason?

Comment: mayjune it could in  theory, but won't in practice. The OS will respawn certain services if you kill them off, however.

Comment: @mayjune: in the firefox example when you open multiple tabs,multiple firefox processes are not created but in case of google chrome when you open multiple tabs,multiple processes are created. so it depends on the program you are using that whether it spawns of a thread or creates a new process. You cannot create 2 instances of VLC player on windows but you can do so on Linux. So it depends on the programmer how he has actually made the program

Comment: Just to add, processes each have their own memory allocated by the operating system. looking at it this make, you can clearly see that you can have multiple processes running at the same time (different memory segments). However, as other's have said, it depends on whether the program will allow multiple instances to be launched.

Answer (score 6):

It is most definitely possible but a desktop application might not be a good example and I think this is the source of your confusion.

Consider a webserver instead (NginX or Apache). There is one master process and multiple worker processes at work. The master process "accpets" the work , so to speak, and delegates it to the workers. Both NginX and Apache could be configured to any number of worker processes.

At our company we are in the business of delivering a SaaS that helps businesses have an online chat with their visitors via their websites. The back-end part of our system has multiple "service"es communicating with each other to accomplish the task. Each service has multiple instances running.

Comment: But are those multiple processes or multiple threads?

Comment: @user1 in this particular example (our won system) it was multiple processes, each process being single threaded. It is possible to make the same thing by single process and multiple threads (instead of multiple single-threaded processes) and multiple processes, each one multi-treaded.

Comment: @user1 in my latest company we have a vast micro services application. Some services have only one instance running but that instance is multi-threaded (Akka, ZIO or cats-effect. We have them all, sometimes in combination), some services have two instances running (each instance being multi-threaded). Also we have some functions within some of those services that *has* to be singletons so we took measure to make sure only one of the multiple instances of the running service takes the role of doing that particular function via zookeeper leader election mechanism. Hope this helps.